# python pandas merge with any one value

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data sets like

```
region  codes
A   GXM|GMR|MDK
B   APN|MGK|MMD
C   PPR|PXP|RGM
D   ALO|OMR|OGK
E   ATK|TLO|AOR
F   MKM|FXP|OZP
G   AMM|BZA|TEL

code    pcode
AOL 1001
GMR 1002
PPR 1003
OGK 1004
FXP 1005
BZA 1006
```

The output I'm looking for is

```
region  codes   code    pcode
A   GXM|GMR|MDK GMR 1002
C   PPR|PXP|RGM PPR 1003
D   ALO|OMR|OGK OGK 1004
F   MKM|FXP|OZP FXP 1005
G   AMM|BZA|TEL BZA 1006
```

Codes in first data set to be matched with code in the second one. Any one of the codes should match with the second one.

Comment: What that exactly you have tried so far to achieve the required result.

Comment: i could not find any option to do this fuzzy match, i see merge works with an exact match ??

Comment: Sorry it's unclear to me where your first df has 1/2/3 columns

Comment: the first df has 2 columns. the 2nd column contains a concatenated string with '|' .

Comment: Show what you tried to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little messed up, firstly split the 'codes' column on the separator and `apply` `map` to each element and pass the other df with the index set to 'code', this will perform a lookup, we reduce this to just the codes that match.

We then generate an intermediate df from this, we reapply the splitting to the original df to add the 'pcode' column, this then allows us to `merge`:

```
In [246]:
matching_codes = df['codes'].str.split('|', expand=True).apply(lambda x: x.map(df1.set_index('code')['pcode'])).dropna(axis=0,thresh=1).sum(axis=1)
matching_codes

Out[246]:
0    1002
2    1003
3    1004
5    1005
6    1006
dtype: float64

In [249]:
matching_df = df1[df1['pcode'].isin(matching_codes)]
matching_df

Out[249]:
  code  pcode
1  GMR   1002
2  PPR   1003
3  OGK   1004
4  FXP   1005
5  BZA   1006

In [254]:
df['pcode'] = df['codes'].str.split('|', expand=True).apply(lambda x: x.map(matching_df.set_index('code')['pcode'])).sum(axis=1)
df.merge(matching_df, on='pcode')

Out[254]:
  region        codes  pcode code
0      A  GXM|GMR|MDK   1002  GMR
1      C  PPR|PXP|RGM   1003  PPR
2      D  ALO|OMR|OGK   1004  OGK
3      F  MKM|FXP|OZP   1005  FXP
4      G  AMM|BZA|TEL   1006  BZA
```

Comment: Thanks alot EdChum.. i m using the pyzo distribution python 3.2.5 expand= True, it says TypeError: split() got an unexpected keyword argument 'expand' . i ll check with the latest one